# How do I override Shopify existing product image position with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, shopify

I am using the Shopify API with Ruby and I am trying to understand the flow of posting a new product image into an existing product into position 1 and overriding\rearranging the position of the current image into position 2.

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(123456789)
products.images << ShopifyAPI::Image.new(:src=> "http://website/CF01.jpg", :position=> 1)
products.save
```

When setting the current image position to 2 it changes the position attribute but not the actual position of the image on the store, even setting the position to nil doesn't work. Do I need to completely remove and re-upload the current image(s) to get the new image in the first position? Should I be trying to access the ShopifyAPI::Image end point instead?

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(123456789)
products.images[0].position = 2
products.images << ShopifyAPI::Image.new(:src=> "http://website/CF01.jpg", :position=> 1)
products.save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading the image to the product and saving it then changing the position on the first image then the new image and saving again seemed to have worked.

```
#this is based on a product with 1 image
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(id)
products.images << ShopifyAPI::Image.new(:src=> "http://website.com/image.jpg")
products.save
products.images[0].position = 2
products.images[1].position = 1
products.save
```